# Is there a way to convert strings into column names using SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to perform some mathematical operations on some columns based on rules set out in a secondary table.

Some example data.

```
HoursWorked   HoursEarned   Earnings1   Earnings2   Earnings3   Earnings4
40            55            120         60          60          80
30            40            160         40          50          90
20            48            130         70          90          120
```

I will also have, in a separate table that is easy to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with, the rules I need to have happen such as this.

```
ThingDesc1   ThingVal1   ThingRule1   ThingBasedOn1   ThingDesc2   ThingVal2   ThingRule2   ThingBasedOn2   ThingDesc3   ThingVal3   ThingRule3   ThingBasedOn3
Working      .03         W            NULL            Earning      1.03        E            NULL            Percentage   2.5         P            E1-E2,E4
```

The output would need to look a bit like this.

```
HoursWorked   HoursEarned   Earnings1   Earnings2   Earnings3   Earnings4   Working   Earning   Percentage
40            55            120         60          60          80          1.2       56.65     6.5
30            40            160         40          50          90          0.9       41.20     7.25
20            48            130         70          90          120         0.6       49.44     8
```

Presuming I am doing this correctly, the `E` and `W` rules are very easy to follow as they are simply HoursWorked * ThingVal1 and HoursEarned * ThingVal2.

But it gets beyond me at the 'Percentage' rules because of the special 'ThingBasedOn' rules which only use parts of the first table.

My initial bits of making this generic code would be something like this.

```sql
--Working
CASE
START
WHEN [ThingRule1] = 'W' THEN [HoursWorked] * [ThingVal1]
WHEN [ThingRule1] = 'E' THEN [HoursEarned] * [ThingVal1]
WHEN [ThingRule1] = 'P' THEN [ThingVal1] * 0.01 * 
    (CONVERT_[ThingBasedOn1]_TO_USABLE_COLUMNS)
ELSE 'Something Went Wrong'
END AS 'Working'
```

Repeat as needed for the other rules. Where the `CONVERT_[ThingBasedOn1]_TO_USABLE_COLUMNS` would become `[Earnings1]+[Earnings2]+[Earnings3]`.

Thus the issue at hand is the `[ThingBasedOn]` column value which will/can be a string according to the rules below.

Comma Separated values indicating a single column, and dash separated values indicating a range of columns.

such as `E1-E8,E13,E15` for columns E1 to E8 and E13 and E15.

another `E5,E6,E7` for columns E5 and E6 and E7.

last `E1-E3` for columns E1 to E3.

With all that in mind, what is the best way to convert this string value into usable columns?

Comment: First create a query with only the calculated columns that do not depend on other calculated columns. Then wrap it in another `select * from (select ...)`, and how you can use the calculated columns names to calculate more columns. Repeat the wrapping was needed.

Comment: I don't think you are going to be able to do this as one query.  If I understand right, you want to use the results of the query (the `ThingBasedOn`] as part of the query definition.  You will have to get that data first (the one with all the "Thing" columns, then take the results to create your query.  At that point it is dynamic SQL, which can be dangerous if the values of `ThingBasedOn` can be entered by users.

Comment: Vaccano you make a good point about entered by users. Thankfully, while that is 'technically' possible, said users also follow a strict data validation policy. Thus I am not overly concerned.

Answer (score 0):

First create a temporary table to keep data of **column name**(Earnings1,Earnings2..) and their **ID** (E1, E2..etc).
Then create a query with the calculated data with the where clause of the condition of **ThingBasedOn3**

Something like-

```
create table #temp
(
    id int,
    colName varchar(100)
)
insert into #temp
values (1,'a'),(2,'b'), (3,'c'), (4,'d')

DECLARE @strName VARCHAR(100) 
SELECT @strName = 'TestID-' +  colName from #temp where id = 2
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @sql = 'select COLUMN_NAME as ' + QUOTENAME(@strName) + ' from TABLE_NAME' 
PRINT @sql 
EXEC(@sql)
drop table #temp
```